# setup google services libgdx on netbeans

Tags: netbeans, libgdx, google-play-services

I'm using netbeans and I'm trying to add admob via google play services to my libgdx project. My problem is that I really can't find a way to add the library to the project. Followed quite a few tutorials, but most of them are for eclipse and not netbeans. I copied the google-play-services_lib to the main folder of the project but I'm kind of lost from there. Any hints?

Comment: It might be a good time to switch to Eclipse, or better Android Studio.

Comment: Android Studio is really only for android. You can't really work with java projects on it. As for Eclipse, yes I've considered it, but it's a bit slower than Netbeans and that's why I prefer it. But yeah, I'll end up using Eclipse if simple tasks need that much manual tweaking. Anyhow, I actually managed to make it work. Did a few changes here and there, but I think the fix was adding to build.gradle the following: `code`compile files('google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar')`code`